# Android: Is it possible to use photo taken from camera in same activity it was initiated from?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-camera, android-view

I currently have an activity that adds a camera preview (which extends surfaceview) to its layout and then uses that to get a photo from the user.  I then pass that photo to a new activity.    I am wondering if it is possible to just take the photo and then pop it open in the same activity? I suppose I would just remove the camera preview and then pop open a new view and add the taken photo to it? Not sure if this is the way to go.  I just find it annoying that I need to pass the photo to the next activity by saving the photo to the SD card and such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some advantages to using two Activities for this purpose:

- Back button allows the user to take the picture again if they are not satisfied. Clicking back might be the first thing they do and they don't expect to go two logic steps back. I think this is very important from a design point of view and you get it for free when using two Activities.
- Automatic removal of all camera controls that are unnecessary when viewing the picture
- You can declare all UI in XML not in code

But, you can use two Fragments instead of Activities, to get above bonuses and avoid saving image to file. One fragment is for camera preview. The other for displaying picture.

In `onPictureTaken()` callback, use `decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length)` to obtain a `Bitmap`. Pass it to the "camera" fragment. Create a `FragmentTransaction` in which hide the "camera" fragment and show the "display" fragment. Add transaction to BackStack and commit.

Be sure to properly close camera in `Framgent.onPause()`.